# VirtueMart "Add to cart" of Ajax element sends to empty Cart/Checkout page

Tags: jquery, ajax, joomla, infinite-scroll, virtuemart

I am developing a module to load Virtumemart products with Ajax pagination system.

It's simple for example the fist load there is 4 products with a "load more" button when it will be clicked 4 more products will be loaded to the page using infinite scroll and manual trigger javascript plugins.

the problem is the add to cart button works only on the first loaded products (the first 4 products loaded, but it won't work on the new added products via Ajax.)

I don't know how "add to cart" system works but I think it's because of "vmprices.js" which is already loaded and it will not take effects on the new added products via Ajax

can you please suggest a solution to make the add to cart option works on the new loaded products via Ajax (the page will not be refreshed or loaded again, only the products are loaded via Ajax)

there is a call back function in infinite scroll I think I should add some code there to reload the script in order to recognizing the new added products:

```
$container.infinitescroll({
navSelector  : '#page_nav',
nextSelector : '#page_nav a',
itemSelector : '.item',
debug        : false,
path:["fetcher.php?modid=93&perpage=3&page=", ""],
behavior: 'twitter',
loading: {
 finishedMsg: '<p class="msg">No more pages</p>',
img: 'loading.gif',
msgText: "<em>Loading</em>",
speed: 'slow'
 }
 },
 function( newElements ) {
 $container.iso( 'insert', $( newElements ) );  
 }
```

);

Thank you in advance, it's really my only option to post here.

Answer (score 0):

This may happen due to the click events not triggering on dynamically loaded HTML section.

that is when the Ajax loaded content display on the browser with 4 products its click events not works bcoz the click event registering time those HTML section not in the document.

Solution is check the add to cart button code its written with normal `jQuery click()`  change that to `on()` or `live()` event based on your `jQuery` version.

For eg:

```
 jQuery('.addtocart').click(function(){
  //code for adding items to the cart
  });
```

Change to if you are using jquery 1.7 or less use `live()`

```
 jQuery('.addtocart').live('click',function(){
      //code for adding items to the cart
      });
```

For above jQuery1.7 version.

```
 jQuery('.addtocart').on('click',function(){
      //code for adding items to the cart
      });
```

Hope its works..